# Debugging promises in my angular controller, very difficult without filename and lineno in err message

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I got a bunch of functions included, and in one of them there is an error, but which one and where?   How can I see that?

This is where the browser reports the error:

```
Promise.all([findProperties])
    .then(makeReport)
    .then(showReport)
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("ERROR: " + err.message );
        console.log("ERROR: " + err.file );
        console.log("ERROR: " + err.lines );
        throw new Error('Higher-level error. ' + err);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("reportAgentSaleController ERROR: " + err);
    })
```

Like 63 is the first console.log

```
index.js:63 ERROR: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
index.js:64 ERROR: undefined
index.js:65 ERROR: undefined
index.js:69 ERROR: Error: Higher-level error. TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Its really hard to find that error when I got 9 includes with hundreds of lines of code full of replace commands.

How can I find out where and in what file it goes wrong?

**EDIT - Trying with reject**

Here is an example.
Console log will return like this

```
here comes the error (line 114)
err: ReferenceError: conXXXsole is not defined (line 102)
```

The error is actually in line 115, so how do I get it to tell me that its in line 115?

```
function testErr(){

    var first = new Promise(
        (resolve, reject) => {
        if (1==1) {
            resolve();
        } else 
            reject();
    });


    var second = function(){
        var test=funcWithErr('aaa');
    }

    Promise.all([first])
        .then(second)
        .catch(err => { console.log('err: ' + err) }
)}


function funcWithErr(text){

    console.log ('here comes the error')  // line 114
    conXXXsole.log ('this is the error')  // line 115

    return text;
}
```

Comment: try using "debugger" at places where u think the problem is. What that does is it pauses the rendering and u can then see, whats happening

Comment: @Plankton how do you do that?   Is there something I have to turn on in CHROME or ?

Comment: its just "debugger;" thats it. See https://www.ng-book.com/p/Debugging-AngularJS/ (look for the section marked "Debugger")

Comment: If makeReport() and showReport() are having async operations, and something is going wrong there, then the throw would have to be in there and the catch section would just catch it. Just thought of mentioning.

Comment: @Plankton yes they do - and the error is in makeReport (among hundreds of lines of code).  So do I just add a throw new Error to that function?  How would you go about doing that?

Comment: Yes, u will have to add a throw in the nested async call (in makeReport or showReport). If there was NO async, then we could've used reject(), but since there are nested async calls, reject() doesnt remain visible. So, wherever in the nested async calls, u think there is an error occuring, u should throw the error . then the catch blocks (like u wrote) can catch the thrown errors. In such a case, the catch-blocks WILL NOT throw errors.

Comment: @Plankton I added an example to my question - is that what you mean?  Perhaps you can show me how I can make that one show the correct line of the error.

Comment: console.log is the opposite of debugging. Want to get call stack? Use console.error, console.warn or leave the promise uncaught. Or even better, use a debugger, as suggested above. A single `debugger;` statement does the job even without breakpoints.

Comment: @estus all debugger; do is break the page, and since its async the page just continues despite of the break. So to me it seems pretty useless.  Are there chrome settings I need to set or?

Comment: @estus Ouuuu!!!! `console.error();` - that did the trick!!  It tells me exactly what file the error is in and what line and everything.  That was awesome, thanks!! - The debugger; - im still not sure how that one works (other than try to break the script).

Comment: The script should become paused ('paused' message), and the line is highlighted in Sources tab. I'm not sure if there's something in settings that can break this behaviour. If you have problems with debugger, I would suggest to investigate it and probably ask a new question (it's not relevant to Angular).

Comment: @estus ok thanks - if you post a solution with the console.error(err); then I will approve. Cause this was the tip that solved all my problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` isn't supposed to help it debugging, it's only purpose is to log a message.

There's a number of [console methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console) that output call stack, namely `error`, `warn` and `trace`. One of them may be used depending on the context.

If it's a critical error it can be `console.error(error)`, and if it's expected error it can be `console.warn(error)`.

The idiomatic way in AngularJS is to use `$exceptionHandler` service:

```
$exceptionHandler(error)
```

> The default implementation simply delegates to $log.error which logs it into the browser console.

And `$log` just uses `console`:

> Default implementation safely writes the message into the browser's console (if present).

ES6 promise implementation provides default handler for uncaught promises (this behavior is true for some modern browsers and also `core-js` polyfill). For the purpose of debugging the error can be re-thrown in `catch` and result in error:

```
.catch(err => {
    console.log("reportAgentSaleController ERROR: " + err);
     throw err;
})
```

Comment: the problem i have faced with an overridden/decorated $exceptionHandler is that the cause section is not always populated. So, doesn't seem to working everytime to me.

Comment: @Plankton Not sure what you mean. `cause` is optional. And sure, if the service wasn't implemented correctly, this will result in having problems with it.